# Multisim Circuit with Virtual Crystal and TTL gates

Tags: ttl, multisim

I have to make the following circuit in Multisim:
[image]

This is what I have done:
[image]

As you can see, the output (in points ~Q and Q) is 0V and I can't figure out why. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Where's the power going to your gates?

Answer (score 0):

That's because 7405 has open collector outputs so it is completely wrong chip for the job. The least you can do is to use a chip with normal outputs like 7404.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and now I have a rectangular signal as an output, but the problem is that it's the same for both Q and ~Q which is not ok because they are complementary